# Displaying variable values in hexadecimal with xcode during debug does not work anymore (xcode 3.2.3)

Tags: xcode, debugging, hex

I switched to xcode 3.2.3 last week and curiously I cannot display variable values in hexadecimal during the debug process.

When I open Run > Variable views then all options remain gray except the first two ones (Use data Formatters / Show Type Column).

Did someone notice this? Why such a change?

Franz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed something similar; I assume it's a bug.

What worked for me was to stop at a breakpoint and toggle the "Use Data Formattters" option off and on; that seemed to enable the other options.

Comment: On my side, disabling "Use Data Formattters" has no effect, still gray.